# Export to Excel Not Working in WEB API

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, jqgrid, export-to-excel

I am trying to export to excel a JQGrid data from WEB API controller ..Need to handle it from a controller method ..Everything is going fine but Excel is not showing ....

```
<input type="image" src="../images/Excel.jpg" alt="Submit" width="20" height="20"
                                    id="btnExport" runat="server" onclick="ExportData();" />


function ExportData() {
    //debugger;
    var tblHTML = createGridStructureForPrint($("#table3"));
    tblHTML = escape(tblHTML);
    var ExportData = tblHTML;
    var source = {
        'ExportData': ExportData
    };
    var apiUrlExport = '../api/Home/ExportData?source=' + source ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: apiUrlExport,
        beforeSend: function () {

            $('#dvStatus').show("slow");

        },
        data: JSON.stringify(source),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;

        },
        error: function (ex) {

        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#dvStatus').hide("slow");
        }
    });

};

[HttpPost]
        public void ExportData(ExportToExcel source)
        {
            try
            {
                string data = source.ExportData;
                data = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Data.xls");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
                System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                sw.Write(data.ToString());
                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Not sure where i am doing wrong ..

Comment: When you say "everything is going fine." does that mean that the data is getting to Excel, and the application is not loading after you've sent the data to it? Or is the data not getting to Excel?

Comment: "everything is going fine." - Means it is seamless between client to server side ..even i can see the proper data in server side but getting problem while writing and flushing the excel

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, you might want to look into JQGrid.ExportSettings and JQGrid.ExportToExcel. I have found it simpler than Http Response...